# Multiple storage containers in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, storage, openstack-swift

Is it possible in Django to store image files in different buckets/containers in external object storage OpenStack Swift?

I have an issue related with creating proper way to upload image files through REST service request. The user is able to POST 'Task' instance via first endpoint, containing name, description, owner_id etc. He is also able to POST images via another endpoint, which has a relation many to one with Task.

Images should be stored in OpenStack Swift in my case (server already exists, was set up etc.) in unique containers/buckets as follows: owner_id_task_id. It is related, that users can upload files with the same names and extensions, but different content.
Another part will be sending also to the same containers in OpenStack Swift a files from Celery worker tasks (some processing based on uploaded files).

My goal is to achieve dynamically-created/overrided at runtime container structure, for storing raw images, and also post-processed images.

Any ideas how this problem can be solved?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: its not only possible but recommended. For example Heroku suggests users to use s3 for static and media files https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

A django solution for this would be using "whitenoise" but its more for static files and not scaling for bigger files.

Comment: @hansTheFranz to be more specific: I would like to upload images to OpenStack Swift to unique containers called '{1}_{2}'.format(user_id, task_id). The user_id I took from request.user, task_id from REST request. So containers should be named for example like: '12_05' or '23_111'. Is it possible to do such of thing?

Comment: Im not an OpenStack expert I cannot tell you how they managed the name policy for the Containers but in general you should be able to call them like you want. But it seems that you want to create a container for each user? I don't think that is the best practice for OpenStack. Please tell us in the Question what you want to do and WHY. Maybe you are working around a solution which could be achieved easier using another path.

Comment: @hansTheFranz I updated my Question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible. You can use [`FileField.storage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage) to configure which storage to use in individual model fields.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a solution for my issue. Check the edited Question, please.

Comment: You didn't ask for a solution. You asked whether it is possible. If you have a specific problem, you're more likely to get an answer if you ask a specific question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Firstly I was wondering whether that issue can be manage in Django though : ) but If you know any solution how to solve my problem, feel free to share it with me : )